# Why is the base to base characteristics of UJT a straight line passing through the origin?

Tags: device-characteristics

Why is the base to base characteristics of UJT a straight line passing through the origin?
and what do you mean by offstate resistance of ujt??

Answer (score 0):

Straight line: It acts as a resistor when tested between the bases I=U/R and that's a straight line.

Offstate = no emitter current, that would be mixed with base to base current

R in the first line is the interbase off state resistance. It's useful only, if IE = 0